# Extending followers sub document to controllers in Mongoose/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So currently I have a subdocument with an array of objectIDs that users can add who they'd like to follow. I'm just unsure of how to implement a crud module correctly with the subdocument belonging to an authenticated user. And unfortunately stuck at the update state.

Currently this is how my schema looks:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
  },
  displayName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: 'testing error message',
    required: 'Please fill in a username',
    trim: true
  },
  //* For following we create an array of ObjectId's*//
  following: [{
    type: ObectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }], 

});
```

A lot of the schema was removed for brevity.

And this is what I have so far for updating the array, but it doesn't seem to work when I test.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var _ = require('lodash'),
    errorHandler = require('../errors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User');

/**
 * Updating Following array
 */
exports.update = function(req, res){
  var user = req.user; 

  delete req.body.roles; 

  user.following = .push(_.extend(user, req.body));

  user.following.save(function(err){
    if (err){
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(following);
    }
  });
};
```

Again some stuff is removed for brevity.

Comment: how do you invoke `exports.update()`? what is your failure case?

Comment: also `user.following = .push(_.extend(user, req.body));` looks wrong you probably want `user.following.push(_.extend(user, req.body));` (assuming the thing you want to add to the following array is req.user plus the req.body properties)

Comment: It's supposed to be invoked via  an angular service but at the moment I'm running a mocha test, and I'm not getting expected results. I'll try and change the push state, and see if that works. This is my first jump into a mean stack and I figured I wasn't using the property correctly. And it was foolish of me to add the the req.user.

Comment: You probably aren't. req.user is probably the CURRENT user, so you will be adding it to itself. I am going to guess that what you actually want is `user.following.push(req.body)` but i dunno what you are trying to extend

Comment: I thought I would have to extend the current user, the one requesting it, and then add the req.body (the new person the current user wants to follow) to the array for the current user,

Comment: What properties do you think need to be extended to the current user? Don't you already have a `following` property?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the lodash use of .extend. Thanks for your help Plato , and I'm going to edit my controller to see if my test returns my expectations.

Comment: FYI - the .extend is to append a destination object to source object. .assign is the new .extend.